# Security Certs for multiple domains in postfix

Tags: server, email, postfix, certificates

In postfix when configuring for multiple domains do I need the following lines in /etc/postfix/main.cf for each domain or something else? I already have certs for the domains in question from letsencrypt.

Certificate is saved at: /etc/letsencrypt/live/your_domain/fullchain.pem
Key is saved at:         /etc/letsencrypt/live/your_domain/privkey.pem

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need *one* SSL certificate with numerous domains added to it.

Otherwise, hostname resolution will fail on TLS and you get a mismatched domain.

I.E. you need to run `certbot` with numerous `-d` entries for each domain (i.e. `certbot certonly -d domain1.com -d domain2.com -d sub1.domain1.com -d sub2.domain1.com ...` with additional `-d ...` entries for each domain / subdomain you want to match against.)